# Post comment as logged in user

Tags: php

I have a system where you can post a comment and it writes to a database, the user is required to write their name and comment.

What I'm trying to achieve is if a user is logged in, it will retrieve their username and post it as the name.

My log-in works perfectly fine

This is what I have so far

```
$_SESSION['user_username']= $username;
```

This is the script that links to the form where users post a comment. I get a `line 7 error` when I try to post the comment.

```
if (isset($_POST['comment_submit'])) {

$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comments (comment_username, comment_description, comment_art)
VALUES (:comment_user, :comment_desc, :comment_article)');

    $criteria = [
        'comment_user' => $_POST[$username],
        'comment_desc' => $_POST['comment_description'],
        'comment_article' => $_GET['article_id']
    ];

$stmt->execute($criteria);
}
```

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: can you post complete error you received ? it will let us help you better

Comment: `'comment_user' => $_POST[$username],` will not work. Use `'comment_user' => $username,`

Comment: @jqheart sorry - 
Notice: Undefined variable: username on line 7

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you have any errors? What have you tried to fix it? Please read and follow the instructions on this page to produce a high-quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment the code,

```
$_SESSION['user_username']= $username;
```

should be like

```
 $username= $_SESSION['user_username'];
```

The variable `$username` is not initialised.

Also use,

```
 $criteria = [
        'comment_user' => $username, //Edited
        'comment_desc' => $_POST['comment_description'],
        'comment_article' => $_GET['article_id']
    ];
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I did this and it posted the username of my database log-in haha. this is because it's called $username. I changed the name for the variable for the comment posting, but now it doesn't do anything when I try submit. Doesn't even give me an error